# Is this [a] + [b] = [a + b] a well defined operation for this equivalence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

x ~ y iff x and y round to the same integer

[a] + [b] = [a + b]

it asks if this is a well-defined operation.

What exactly does this mean? How do I check for it?

Further, what does it mean to add two equivalence classes? (left side of equation)

This is on the real numbers btw.

Answer (score 2):

$$[a] + [b] = [a + b]$$ is not well-defined for example,$$ [2.4]+[3.4]=[2]+[3]=[5]$$

while $$[2.4+3.4]=[5.8]=[6]$$

Comment: So does well-defined just mean true for all a and b?

Comment: It's not "well-defined" because it doesn't do what it says it will..... Namely $[a] +[b]\neq[a+b]$.  Put another way, if we require $[a] +[b]=[a+b]$ then we get $[5] = [2]+[3] = [2.4]+[3.4] = [2.4+3.4] = [5.8] = [6]$ but very clearly $[5]\neq [6]$.

Comment: Yes, it does mean true for all a and b.

Comment: "Rounding" is actually a bit of a vague word. For example, what do $2.5$ and $3.5$ round to? Some people would say $3$ and $4$ while others would say $2$ and $4$.

Comment: Also, some people use [x] to mean the fractional part of x while others use it to mean the integer part of x.